# Итерация по Б-дереву

Tags: python, дерево

В моем дереве находится структура данных и мне нужно реализовать поиск по определенному полю, для чего надо пройтись по всему дереву. Функция поиска просто игнорирует одну из веток

```
class _Node:
    def __init__(self, is_leaf=False):
        self.is_leaf = is_leaf
        self.keys = []
        self.child = []


class BTree:
    def __init__(self, t=2):
        self.root = _Node(True)
        self.t = t  # defines the range for number of keys

    def search_by_record_book(self, value, node):
        for i in range(len(node.keys)):
            #print(node.keys[i].record_book)
            if value == node.keys[i].record_book:
                print("Node was found:", node.keys[i])
                return
            # elif node.is_leaf:
            #     return self.search_by_record_book(value, node.child[i])
        if len(node.child) > 0:
            for x in node.child:
                return self.search_by_record_book(value, x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

или делаете

```
arr = [key for key in i.record_book]
```

или используете i как индекс

```
for i in range(len(node.keys)):
```

но при этом нельзя менять переменную цикла внутри него же (`i += 1`), и вам, вероятно, требуется

```
arr = [key for key in node.keys[i+1].record_book]
```

Comment: Да, теперь компилируется, но проверяет только 3 значения из 8

Comment: Нам неизвестны ваши структуры данных, нынешнее состояние кода, и сколько там реально значений. Отладкой посмотрите.

Comment: В общем, он почему-то смотрит  только одну ветку в дереве

Comment: Сейчас включу телепатор, и всё узнаю про ваш код... Отредактируйте вопрос, включив актуальный код и минимально необходимое описание структур данных, если оно небольшого размера.

Comment: Изменил, надеюсь вы увидите то, чего не вижу я..

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что на последней строке функции:  `return self.search_by_record_book(value, x)`
надо было просто убрать return...